# Image not saving to media or creating media folder (Python, Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have been struggling with this for the past days i have done everything right and i dont know what am missing exactly.

when i try to upload the image from the admin page it uploads succesfully creates the media folder if not exist already.

but when i try to get the image from url the image is saved in the url field of my model but never get create to the image field of my model whis is image = image = models.ImageField

below is my code

models

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="user_images", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="images_liked", blank=True
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/%Y/%m/%d/")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(
        auto_now_add=True, db_index=True
    )
```

forms save method

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
            image = super().save(commit=False)
            image_url = self.cleaned_data["url"]
            name = slugify(image.title)
            extension = image_url.rsplit(".", 1)[1].lower()
            image_name = f"{name}.{extension}"
            # download image from the given URL
            response = request.urlopen(image_url)
            image.image.save(image_name, ContentFile(response.read()), save=False)
            if commit:
                image.save()
            return image
```

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / "static/"]  # routes to search for static files
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, "staticfiles/"
)  # django collects all static files here


# MEDIA
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
```

Comment: Could you add your `settings.py` file `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` config?

Comment: i think the media root is okay because when i upload through the admin page everything works fine ... but i want to save the downloaded image to the model field (image)

Answer (score 1):

In your views.py, while trying to extract data from the form, instead of

```
form_data=MyForm(request.POST)
```

replace it by

```
form_data = Myform(request.POST,request.FILES)
```

Also, try to validate your form input by over-riding the initial validate function and make sure, you receive an image with proper format to make your life easier

Comment: Thanks and yes am already validating the form input also am using the `form_data=MyForm(data=request.POST)` which gets all the data